# php выборка из бд одной функцией

Tags: php, mysql

как одной функцией выбирать из нескольких таблиц, чтобы было типа:
"SELECT * FROM ***здесь задать переменную с именем таблицы*** ORDER BY id ASC";

Comment: http://www.sql.ru/articles/mssql/2007/013001introductiontojoins.shtml        .........http://pionick.net/examples/mysql_join ...........http://www.skillz.ru/dev/php/article-Obyasnenie_SQL_obedinenii_JOIN_INNER_OUTER.html

Comment: Раз вы это делаете из php, то имя таблицы у вас спокойно может быть в переменной. никто не мешает же вам написать `$sql="select * from $table ..."; ` и потом выполнить сконструированный запрос

Comment: Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.